# MySQL shell on Windows

Tags: mysql, windows, shell

The command line interface to MySQL works perfectly well in itself, but when using my local copy I'm forced to interact with it using the old-fashioned DOS windows. Is there some way I can redirect it through a better shell?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried the [MySQL Query Browser](http://www.mysql.com/products/tools/query-browser/)?  Works cross platform and is much nicer than the plain shell.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a GUI is not really what you were after, but maybe [HeidiSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HeidiSQL) would be worth a look. It's a GUI frontend for MySQL which I wouldn't say I quite *enjoyed* using, but I've certainly come across worse ways to talk with a database.

Answer (score 0):

You should give a try to [SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php). It has very powerfull query editor with features including Auto-complete, Auto-indentation, Customize foreground and background colours, Flexibiility to execute multiple MySQL queries in one go, and a long list to go... [SQLyog Documentation for Query Tab](http://www.webyog.com/doc/SQLyog/#Syntax_Highlighting_for_SQLyog_GUI_for_MySQL.htm)

[image: SQLyog's Query Tab Screenshot]

Hope it helps...