# How to obtain a correct dump using mysqldump and single-transaction when DDL is used at the same time?

Tags: mysql, corruption

I'm new to MySQL and I'm figuring out the best way to perform an on-line hot logical backup using `mysqldump`.  [This page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-policy.html) suggests this command line:

```
mysqldump --single-transaction --flush-logs --master-data=2
          --all-databases > backup_sunday_1_PM.sql
```

but... if you read the documentation carefully [you find that](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction):

> While a `--single-transaction` dump is in process, to ensure a valid dump file
>   (correct table contents and binary log position), no other connection should use
>   the following statements: `ALTER TABLE, DROP TABLE, RENAME TABLE, TRUNCATE TABLE`. A
>   consistent read is not isolated from those statements, so use of them on a table to
>   be dumped can cause the `SELECT` performed by `mysqldump` to retrieve the table contents
>   to obtain incorrect contents or fail.

So, is there any way to prevent this possible dump corruption scenario?
I.e. a commands that could block those statements temporarily.

PS: MySQL bug entry on this subject http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27850

Comment: Hi, given the fact that, in months, nobody posted a way to prevent the scenario I assume that is not possible. I accept Bill's answer as good.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21870537/1815624

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open a `mysql` command window and issue this command:

```
mysql> FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;
```

This will lock *all* tables in *all* databases on this MySQL instance until you issue `UNLOCK TABLES` (or terminate the client connection that holds these read locks).

To confirm this, you can open another command window and try to do an `ALTER`, `DROP`, `RENAME` or `TRUNCATE`.  These commands hang, waiting for the read lock to be released.  Hit Ctrl-C to terminate the waiting.

But while the tables have a read lock, you can still perform a `mysqldump` backup.

The `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` command *may* be the same as using the `--lock-all-tables` option of `mysqldump`.  It's not totally clear, but [this doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html) seems to support it:

> Another use for UNLOCK TABLES is to
>   release the global read lock acquired
>   with FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK.

Both `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` and `--lock-all-tables` use the phrase "global read lock," so I think it's likely that these do the same thing.  Therefore, you should be able to use that option to `mysqldump` and protect against concurrent ALTER, DROP, RENAME, and TRUNCATE.

---

Re. your comment:  The following is from Guilhem Bichot in the MySQL bug log that you linked to:

> Hi. --lock-all-tables calls FLUSH
>   TABLES WITH READ LOCK. Thus it is
>   expected to block ALTER, DROP, RENAME,
>   or TRUNCATE (unless there is a bug or
>   I'm wrong). However, --lock-all-tables
>   --single-transaction cannot work (mysqldump throws an error message):
>   because lock-all-tables locks all
>   tables of the server against writes
>   for the duration of the backup,
>   whereas single-transaction is intended
>   to let writes happen during the backup
>   (by using a consistent-read SELECT in
>   a transaction), they are incompatible
>   in nature.

From this, it sounds like you cannot get concurrent access during a backup, and simultaneously block ALTER, DROP, RENAME and TRUNCATE.

Comment: Thanks Bill, but I want an hot backup: the DB must be accessible for SELECT and INSERT statements while the backup is in progress. This is the reason behind the use of single-transaction (and InnoDB).

Comment: Thanks for Answer, I am bit confused while using mysqldump, if the above you wrote i.e.(no need to open a separate session with FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK;) is confirmed then I can make batch file for timely dump but if its not, then how can i confirm it or how can i create batch file which can create two different sessions according to the need(to hold the lock) ;

Answer (score 2):

I thought the same thing reading that part of the documentation though, I found more information:

4.5.4. mysqldump — A Database Backup Program
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysqldump.html

> For InnoDB tables, mysqldump provides a way of making an online
>   backup:
>
> ```
> shell> mysqldump --all-databases --single-transaction > all_databases.sql
> ```
>
> This backup acquires a global read lock on all tables (using FLUSH
>   TABLES WITH READ LOCK) at the beginning of the dump. As soon as this
>   lock has been acquired, the binary log coordinates are read and the
>   lock is released. If long updating statements are running when the
>   FLUSH statement is issued, the MySQL server may get stalled until
>   those statements finish. After that, the dump becomes lock free and
>   does not disturb reads and writes on the tables. If the update
>   statements that the MySQL server receives are short (in terms of
>   execution time), the initial lock period should not be noticeable,
>   even with many updates.

There is a conflict with the [`--opt`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_opt) and [`--single-transaction`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_single-transaction) options:

> --opt
>
> This option is shorthand. It is the same as specifying
>   --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options --disable-keys --extended-insert --lock-tables --quick --set-charset. It should give you a fast dump operation and produce a dump file that can be reloaded
>   into a MySQL server quickly.
>
> The --opt option is enabled by default. Use --skip-opt to disable it.

If I understand your question correctly you want the actual data and the DDL (Data Definition Language) together, because if you only want the DDL you would use `--no-data`. More information about this can be found at:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-reverse-engineer-create-script.html

> Use the --databases option with mysqldump if you wish to create the
>   database as well as all its objects. If there is no CREATE DATABASE
>   db_name statement in your script file, you must import the database
>   objects into an existing schema or, if there is no schema, a new
>   unnamed schema is created.

As suggested by [The Definitive Guide to MySQL 5 By Michael Kofler](http://books.google.com/books?id=s_87mv-Eo4AC&lpg=PA686&ots=tc_AEaNJxe&dq=%22--opt%20--single-transaction%22&pg=PA354#v=onepage&q=%22--opt%20--single-transaction%22&f=false) I would suggest the follow options:

```
--skip-opt
--single-transaction
--add-drop-table
--create-options
--quick
--extended-insert
--set-charset
--disable-keys
```

Additionally, not mentioned is [`--order-by-primary`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2031061/1815624)
Also if you are using the [`--databases`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_databases) option, you should also use [`--add-drop-database`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_add-drop-database) especially if combined with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16508576/1815624) If you are backing up databases that are connect on different networks you may need to use the [`--compress`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_compress) option.

So a mysqldump command (without using the `--compress`, `--databases`, or `--add-drop-database` options) would be :

```
mysqldump --skip-opt --order-by-primary --single-transaction --add-drop-table --create-options --quick --extended-insert --set-charset -h db_host -u username --password="myPassword" db_name | mysql --host=other_host db_name
```

I removed the reference to `--disable-keys` that was given in the book as it is not effective with InnoDB as i understand it. The [MySql manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_disable-keys) states:

> For each table, surround the INSERT statements with /*!40000 ALTER
>   TABLE tbl_name DISABLE KEYS */; and /*!40000 ALTER TABLE tbl_name
>   ENABLE KEYS */; statements. This makes loading the dump file faster
>   because the indexes are created after all rows are inserted. This
>   option is effective only for nonunique indexes of MyISAM tables.

I also found this bug report http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64309 which has comments on the bottom from [Paul DuBois who also wrote a few books](http://www.amazon.com/gp/search/ref=sr_adv_b/?search-alias=stripbooks&field-author=Paul%20DuBois) to which I have no reference on this specific issue other than those comments found within that bug report.

Now to create the "**Ultimate Backup**" I would suggest to consider something along the lines of this shell script

1. https://github.com/red-ant/mysql-svn-backup/blob/master/mysql-svn.sh

Comment: I have not discussed Master/Slave as mentioned [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16508576/1815624) because that is not an option for me as I can not configure the MySql database I am working with in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get a consistent dump without locking tables. I just do mine during a time of day that the 2 minutes it takes to do the dump isn't noticed.

One solution is to do replication, then back up the slave instead of the master. If the slave misses writes during the backup, it will just catch up later. This will also leave you with a live backup server in case the master fails. Which is nice.

Comment: In light of everything discussed this seems the smart route thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Hi that's late for any answer but the solution arrived in MariaDB with BACKUP STAGE, open source time is relativist :)

Comment: Please, as per the rules, use the comments if you don't have to post code.