# Data change during doing Database backup

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have a question regarding to mysql DB backup:

1.AT 8.00.00 AM ,I do backup Database by using mysqldump command.It somtime takes 5 second to finish.

2.While database backup is inprogress(**At 8.00.01 AM** ), someone make some changes to DB

Will backup version containt data changes of step 2 ?

I have goolge but not found explaination yet.Pls help me !

Answer (score 0):

Percona provides a free tool for this purpose called [xtrabackup](http://www.percona.com/software/percona-xtrabackup).

For InnoDB tables MySQL uses log files to store [DML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language) commands, so that commands can be rolled back and some other things.
You can backup your database (in a non locking way), and after you created the backup you can apply the logs, so that you have a backup which holds the database status when the backup is finished. Don't know the commands without looking them up now, sorry, you'll have to have a look into the documentation.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your mysqldump command and which table the dump is on at the time of the update:

- If you used the --single-transaction option, then, no, it will not contain the late change.
- If you did not use that option then:

  - if the table being updated has not been dumped yet, then yes it will have the change.
  - If the table being updated has been dumped already, then no it won't have the change.

Chances are, you don't want that change in your backup, because you would like your backup to be consistent to a point in time.  Here is some more discussion about all those kinds of things:

[How to obtain a correct dump using mysqldump and single-transaction when DDL is used at the same time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451404/how-to-obtain-a-correct-dump-using-mysqldump-and-single-transaction-when-ddl-is)