# How do I backup a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, database, backup, database-backups

What do I have to consider when backing up a database with millions of entries? Are there any tools (maybe bundled with the MySQL server) that I could use?

Comment: Should this be moved to serverfault.com?

Comment: @Kimvais: Yes, I'd think so. Are answers moved, too?

Comment: I find myself regularly referring to the answers to this question, including my own. External memory. :P

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do backups in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545/how-do-i-do-backups-in-mysql)

Comment: You can simply use this tool http://mysqlbackupftp.com/  for scheduled backups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Depending on your requirements, there's several options that I have been using myself:

- if you don't need hot backups, take down the db server and back up on the file system level, i. e. using tar, rsync or similar.
- if you do need the database server to keep running, you can start out with the [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) tool (a perl script), which locks the tables that are being backed up and allows you to select single tables and databases.
- if you want the backup to be portable, you might want to use [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html), which creates SQL scripts to recreate the data, but which is slower than mysqlhotcopy
- if you have a copy of the db at a certain point in time, you could also just keep the binlogs (starting at that point in time) somewhere safe. This can be very easy to do and doesn't interfere with the server's operation, but might not be the fastest to restore, and you have to make sure you don't miss part of the logs.

Methods I haven't tried, but that make sense to me:

- if you have a filesystem like ZFS or are running on LVM, it might be a good idea to do a snapshot of the database by doing a filesystem snapshot, because they are very, very quick. Just remember to ensure a consistent state of your db during the whole operation, e. g. by doing `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` (and of course, don't forget `UNLOCK TABLES` afterwards)

Additionally:

- you can use a master-slave setup to replicate your production server to either a different machine or a second instance on the same machine and do any of the above to the replicated copy, leaving your production machine alone. Instead of running continously, you can also fire up the slave on regular intervals, let it read the binlog, and switch it off again.
- I think, MySQL cluster and the enterprise licensed version have more tools, but I have never tried them.

Answer (score 6):

Mysqlhotcopy is badly described - it only works if you use MyISAM, and it's not hot.

The problem with mysqldump is the time it takes to restore the backup (but it can be made hot if you have all InnoDB tables, see --single-transaction).

I recommend using a hot backup tool, like what is available in XtraBackup:
http://www.percona.com/docs/wiki/percona-xtrabackup:start

Comment: This comment helped me a lot.  I was unaware of the --single-transaction option, and if you add the --quick option for large DB's it works great!  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Watch out if using mysqldump on large tables using the MyISAM storage engine; it blocks selects while the dump is running on each table and this can take down busy sites for 5-10 minutes in some cases.

Using InnoDB, by comparison, you get non-blocking backups because of its row-level locking, so this is not such an issue.

If you need to use MyISAM, a common strategy is to replicate to a second MySQL instance and do the mysqldump against the replicated copy instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the export tab in phpMyAdmin. phpMyAdmin is the free easy to use web interface for doing MySQL administration.

Comment: Yes it's a good solution, but it's not strictly a back-up solution! He could also achieve it by writing a back-up script and execute it on a repeat basis.

Comment: Agreed but phpMyAdmin is a popular tool and my answer is intended more for the audience than the one guy who asked the question (who might be using the tool).

Answer (score 1):

I think [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html) is the proper way of doing it.

Comment: There's actually no "the" proper way. As Flubba rightly points out, mysqldump locks the tables, which can be unpleasant in production. It's also slower than, for example, mysqlhotcopy.