# Do I have to prevent users from writing or reading the database when I try to backup the database

Tags: mysql, cron, database-backups

I'm going to use a cron job to backup my database and wonder whether this process would affect the users communicating with my website, like post or read contents from my website.
Do I have to prevent the user from reading or writing data to my database when i'm backing up of my database.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it does affect write operations to your db, if you need the db to keep running, you can use the [mysqlhotcopy](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqlhotcopy.html) tool, which locks the tables being backed up.

More info on: [How do I backup a MySQL database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524542/how-do-i-backup-a-mysql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if locking down the tables is a good idea because it means you have taken the OLTP application down. Taking backup does not mean that your database should be unavailable for users.

Let's assume that you have 100 pages in your database, and the backup operation has read 10 pages and is beginning to read 11th. A user changes his data which belongs to 9th page. In your backup that change won't reflect because the backup process read the data from that page which was available at that very moment. But then you need to supplement your full backups with differentials and transaction log backups ,which can cover these changes.

But do not take the database locked for this operation. You can get away with 50 MB tables but when you have a DB where the tables run into GBs, your approach may become questionable.

Cheers!!