# Backup Mysql Databases

Tags: mysql, backup

I wanna reinstall windows on my PC i wanna backup my Databases in MySQL. I have around 30 plus databases. is there an easy way to back up the content and restore it later ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I do backups in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46545/how-do-i-do-backups-in-mysql) and many many others like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `mysqldump -A` to do generate sql dumps for all databases.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html

Alternatively, you can also just copy the acutal data directory.

Edit: apologies for not being specific, as others have noted this will work only ISAM. For innodb, you'll need to backup using mysqldump or another utility such as phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Be careful! If your databases are not MyISAM then copy the data directory may not work!

Answer (score 2):

Use mysqldump to create a database dump of each database. You can later easily recreate the databases from these dumps by running them through mysql. This would be the most generic answer, knowing nothing more of your set-up.

Answer (score 1):

If your databases contains MyISAM tables, then you could just copy the files. Otherwise (using INNODB) this doesn't work.

I assum you don't have the binary log activated, you should use mysqldump.

Take a look at: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/backup-methods.html

You could try with PHPMyADMIN if you don't feel confortable with mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

go to phpmyadmin and export all the database.. After installing wamp in ur new pc.. go to import and import the files you've exported previously..

Answer (score 1):

Have you given the GUI tools a try?

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html

Have a look at the "Backup" option in the MySQL Administrator. The "Restore" option might also be helpful after the backup is done. :-)

Allows you to backup a single db or all db's at once.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SQLyog MySQL GUI](http://www.webyog.com) to backup your database. It has scheduled backup(you can export data into a single file or as multiple files) and backup as SQL dump(The dump will contain SQL statements to create the table and/or populate the table) to take backup and can restore those .SQL files using Execute SQL script tool.

try the tool [here](http://www.webyog.com/en/downloads.php).